# Find the best font for rendering a codepoint

Tags: fonts, unicode

How to find the appropriate font for rendering unicode codepoints ?

`gnome-terminal` find that characters like «⼼» can be rendered with fonts like Symbola rather than my terminal font or the codepoint-in-square fallback (). How ?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/27598/list-of-fonts-containing-selected-character

Comment: Same question on different sites: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27598/) ■ [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/876572/) ■ [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162305)

Answer (score 41):

Using fontconfig,

```
> fc-list ':charset=<hex_code1> <hex_code2>'
```

e.g.

```
> fc-list ':charset=2713 2717'
```

will display any font filenames containing ✓ and ✗.

To get the codepoint corresponding to the character use (for example)

```
> printf "%x" \'✓
2713>
```

This uses a [somewhat obscure feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890262/integer-ascii-value-to-character-in-bash-using-printf)
of the [POSIX `printf` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html):

> If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote.

Taken together,

```
> printf '%x' \'✓ | xargs -I{} fc-list ":charset={}"
```

This uses the `xargs` `-I` flag to replace `{}` with names from `stdin`. So this effectively boils down to:

```
> fc-list ":charset=2713"
```

Comment: Note that you need a version of `fontconfig` that is [`2.11.91`](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/fontconfig/Devel/) or [later](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7597).

Comment: note that dash `printf` and `/bin/printf` dont support that

Comment: Awesome! I've been looking for info on this for a long time.

Note that you can also specify ranges as well as single characters, so to find all fonts that have all the box-drawing characters, for example: `fc-list --format='%{postscriptname}\n' ':charset=2500-257F'`

Comment: Thanks! Made a gist with simple bash script to streamline it: https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/202550a1e2fd4ea8cf523d91b437fa09

Comment: Is is possible to search specific files by passing filenames instead of the installed system fonts?

Answer (score 16):

This is not necessarily the best method, and it sure isn't user-friendly, but it's easy to get working: here's a Python script to do it.

Install the [Python-fontconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Python-fontconfig) library. Either get it from your distribution (e.g. `sudo apt-get install python-fontconfig` on Debian and derivatives) or install it in your home directory (`pip install --user python-fontconfig)`. Then you can run this script (save it as `fc-search-codepoint` in a directory on your `PATH`, e.g. typically `~/bin`, and make it executable):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re, sys
import fontconfig
if len(sys.argv) < 1:
    print('''Usage: ''' + sys.argv[0] + '''CHARS [REGEX]
Print the names of available fonts containing the code point(s) CHARS.
If CHARS contains multiple characters, they must all be present.
Alternatively you can use U+xxxx to search for a single character with
code point xxxx (hexadecimal digits).
If REGEX is specified, the font name must match this regular expression.''')
    sys.exit(0)
characters = sys.argv[1]
if characters.startswith('U+'):
    characters = unichr(int(characters[2:], 16))
else:
    characters = characters.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
regexp = re.compile(sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else '')

font_names = fontconfig.query()
found = False
for name in font_names:
    if not re.search(regexp, name): continue
    font = fontconfig.FcFont(name)
    if all(font.has_char(c) for c in characters):
        print(name)
        found = True

sys.exit(0 if found else 1)
```

Example usage:

```
$ fc-search-codepoint ⼼
$ echo $?
1
```

I don't have any font with all of these characters.

```
$ fc-search-codepoint U+1F64D
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont_upper.ttf
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont_upper_csur.ttf
```

Comment: Thats a very helpful script! However, it is only python2 compliant, and i suppose it is a bit nasty to do exactly that portable. Would you mind at least changing the `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python2` as per PEP 394.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It was very helpful. I'm sure the OS or system libraries that implement font fallback are doing something more efficient, but this works. @Zulan It can be made to work with `python3` too; I just wrote a smaller version of this at the bottom of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287707/get-list-of-all-fonts-containing-a-specific-character/291200#291200).

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately gnome-terminal uses **[fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/)** to (among other things):

> ...efficiently and quickly find the fonts you need among the set of fonts you have installed, even if you have installed thousands of fonts...

In the [API documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-devel/x102.html) you can find functions to query fonts character ranges and for operations on character ranges, but the documentation is so cryptic that I never could figure out how different sets of functions relate to each other. If I needed to dive deeper I would rather look at examples of usage in other software, perhaps **[vte](https://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/)** (the terminal emulation library used in gnome-terminal).

Another library in between **vte** and **fontconfig** is **[pango](http://www.pango.org/)** *"...a library for laying out and rendering of text, with an emphasis on internationalization..."*. Now that I think of it, it sounds as the one to contain most of the logic you're after.

The character coverage functionality in pango is implemented by [coverage maps](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/unstable/pango-Coverage-Maps.html) (*"It is often necessary in Pango to determine if a particular font can represent a particular character, and also how well it can represent that character. The PangoCoverage is a data structure that is used to represent that information."*), but there are probably more complicated details involved in decided what glyph to render with what font. I guess **VTE** relies on **pango** to render strings with appropriate fonts while **pango** uses **fontconfig** (or other supported font backend) to find the most appropriate font based on various pieced of logic in **pango** itself and/or the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I altered the code to check if a font contains all characters of a certain string. So this can be called by `fc-search-codepoint "$fontname" "$string"` and it returns the exit code 0 on success or 1 otherwise. The font names can be retrieved from `fc-query /path/to/FontSandMonoBoldOblique.ttf` or Imagemagick's `convert -list font`. I use it to check if a user selected string can be rendered with the user selected font and if the command fails, a fallback font is used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re
import sys
import os
import fontconfig
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " 'Fontname-Bold' 'String to check'")
    sys.exit(0)

font_name = sys.argv[1].decode('utf-8')
string = sys.argv[2].decode('utf-8')

if '-' in font_name:
        font_name = font_name.split('-')
        font_style = font_name[-1]
        font_name = ''.join(font_name[:-1])
else:
        font_style = ""

font_names = fontconfig.query()
for name in font_names:
    font = fontconfig.FcFont(name)
    if not len(font.family) > 0:
        continue
    for item in font.family:
        if item[1] == unicode(font_name):
            if len(font_style) == 0:
                match = "yes"
            else:
                for item in font.style:
                    if item[1] == unicode(font_style):
                        match = "yes"
            try:
                match
            except NameError:
                continue
            if all(font.has_char(c) for c in string):
                sys.exit(0)
            else:
                sys.exit(1)
print >> sys.stderr, "font not found: " + font_name + " " + font_style
sys.exit(1)
```