# How do I find which font provides a particular Unicode glyph?

Tags: fonts, unicode

On the Feodora 23 system I upgraded from F22, the U1F32D symbol  shows up just fine in the terminal, but on the one I installed from scratch, I get the box-with-numbers placeholder. I just checked and I have about 60 font packages on the system where it doesn't work, and over 200 where it does. Without inspecting each one manually, is there a way to identify which font I need to add?

Comment: Unfortunately none of the answers in [Gallery of installed fonts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120674/gallery-of-installed-fonts) support this. It would be a useful addition.

Comment: see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268286/119298) for a python script from Gilles, or [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258127/119298)

Answer (score 6):

#### Current Solution

Use, `fc-list :charset=<hexcode>`. Let's say you want the  hotdog emoji.

```
$ printf '\U1F32D\n'

$ fc-list :charset=1F32D
/usr/share/fonts/usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf: Noto Color Emoji:style=Regular
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/393740/

---

#### Pre-2015 Solution.

If you give the command

```
fc-list -v
```

it should list for every font the `charset` property which is a bitmask of which character codes exist in the font. For example, for a simple font like `fc-list -v 'Courier 10 Pitch'` it has lines:

```
charset: 
0000: 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff 7fffffff 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
0001: 00000000 00020000 000c0006 61000003 00040000 00000000 00000000 00000000
...
00fb: 00000006 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Take the hex number in the first column, like the last line `00fb`, and shift it left by 8 bits. It is the start of the unicode value. The bitmask 00000006 says a glyph exists for codes 1 and 2
(`6 = 2+4 = 1<<1 | 1<<2`) which you add to the first column to get `00fb01` and `00fb02`. (These glyphs are, for example, [latin small ligature fi](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb01/index.htm).)

So in the case of `U1F32D` you need to grep for `01f3:` and look for a bit
set at index `2d` in the line, i.e. `00000000 00002000 ...` (*probably!*).
Note the 0's here just show the position of the 2. The actual values may be any hex digit. (A grep pattern *might* be `01f3: ........ ....[2367abef]`).
The preceding `file:` entry should lead you to the package (use `rpm -qf filename`).

But I'm sure there must be a better way to search for a glyph.

Comment: this answer gives *[fc-list ':charset=<hex_code1> <hex_code2>'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162305/find-the-best-font-for-rendering-a-codepoint/393740#393740)*. Sure enough `fc-list ':charset=1F32D'` on my system returns Noto Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji and Segoe UI Symbol.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution that wasn't available in the distribution I had installed at the time. I've updated the answer, but left the info for any historical value it might have.