# How to find out which unicode codepoints are defined in a TTF file?

Tags: fonts, unicode, ttf

I need to automate a process of verification which Unicode characters have actual glyphs defined for them in a True Type Font file. How do I go around doing that? I can't seem to find information on how to make sense of the numbers I seem to be getting when I open a .ttf file in a text editor.

Comment: Same question on StackOverflow: [linux - Finding out what characters a given font supports - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458696/finding-out-what-characters-a-given-font-supports) // related question, [unicode - Find the best font for rendering a codepoint - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162305/find-the-best-font-for-rendering-a-codepoint/393740#393740)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a python library, [fonttools](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools) ([pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FontTools)) that can be used to do it with a bit of python scripting.

Here is a simple script that lists all fonts that have specified glyph:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
import sys

char = int(sys.argv[1], base=0)

print("Looking for U+%X (%c)" % (char, chr(char)))

for arg in sys.argv[2:]:
    try:
        font = TTFont(arg)

        for cmap in font['cmap'].tables:
            if cmap.isUnicode():
                if char in cmap.cmap:
                    print("Found in", arg)
                    break
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to read", arg)
        print(e)
```

First argument is codepoint (decimal or hexa with 0x) and the rest is font files to look in.

I didn't bother trying to make it work for `.ttc` files (it requires some extra parameter somewhere).

Note: I first tried the otfinfo tool, but I only got basic multilingual plane characters (<= U+FFFF). The python script finds extended plane characters OK.

Comment: I don't understand why and how it works, but ... it works giving results which I won't be able to get with `otfinfo`.

Answer (score 13):

[otfinfo](https://www.lcdf.org/type/otfinfo.1.html) looks promising:

```
-u, --unicode
  Print each Unicode code point supported by the font, followed by
  the glyph number representing that code point (and, if present,
  the name of the corresponding glyph).
```

For example DejaVuSans-Bold knows about the fl ligature(ﬂ):

```
$ otfinfo -u /usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf |grep ^uniFB02
uniFB02 4899 fl
```

Comment: This tool is exactly what I need but it also doesn't seem to work with TrueType fonts, only OpenType ones.

Comment: It works with ttf, too. See my example above. (According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) ttf is a special type of OpenType font.)

Comment: Hmm... my version of otfinfo (2.92) doesn't seem to have the -u option at all. Which version are you using?

Comment: I used "otfinfo (LCDF typetools) 2.104" from my [texlive package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/texlive-bin/).

Comment: @Sanuuu, the `-u` option does not appear in `--help`, but still seems to exist. However (at least in Debian 2.105 build) it seems to only list basic plane (up to U+FFFF). The `-g` option knows about the extended planes, but that does not work for all fonts.

Comment: fyi: on mac `otfinfo` can be installed with `brew install lcdf-typetools`

Comment: This is terrific :) I get it through texlive, this is extremely help for Chinese fonts.